# Gitlab pipeline status emails

Tags: gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

I enabled [pipeline status emails](https://docs.gitlab.com/16.4/ee/user/project/integrations/pipeline_status_emails.html) in a self-hosted GitLab in order to get informed about failures, success and fixes from a Jenkins pipeline.

I'm using the [GitLab plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin) in Jenkins and all the pipeline stages are wrapped with `gitlabcommitstatus` method.

I was expecting to receive an email once the pipeline succeeds or fails, but I'm receiving (failure/success) emails on every stage. Should it work that way ? Is there a way to get a single status email per pipeline ?